# Splitting different variables from a text file

Tags: c#, file, variables, split, txtextcontrol

I have a text file that contains Number,Name,LastName looks like this;

```
11, Ali, Guner
32, Ali, ikinci
39, Metin, Tekin
```

I need to seperate this to 3 different parts of a class. How can i do that?
My creating code is this:

```
string[] lines = { "11, Ali, Guner", "32, Ali, ikinci", "39, Metin, Tekin" };
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

I want to have all of this info in one class that named person. i will create a object and will able to call _person1.name

Comment: You say you want to separate it to three string arrays, but not how. Should each array represent a column, or a row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string[]> allLineFields = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Split(','));
```

If you want readable properties with the correct type you should use a custom class:

```
IEnumerable<User> allPeople = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Split(','))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length == 3)
    .Select(arr => new User
    {
        Age = int.Parse(arr[0]), // use int.TryParse to check if it's valid
        FirstName = arr[1],
        LastName = arr[2]
    });
```

with a class `User` like this:

```
public class User
{
    public object FirstName { get; set; }
    public object LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```